# pandas dataframe: perform calculations on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

New to pandas and new to stackoverflow (really), any suggestions are highly appreciated!

I have this dataframe df:

```
            col1     col2     col3
Date                                        
2017-08-24   100      101      105
2017-08-23   102      102      107
2017-08-22   101      100      106
2017-08-21   103       99      106
2017-08-18   103       98      108
...
```

Now I'd like to perform some calculations with the values of each column, e.g. calculate the logarithm of each value.

I thought it's a good idea to loop over the columns and create a new temporary data frame with the resulting columns.
This new data frame should look like this e.g.:

```
            col1       RN      LOG
Date                                        
2017-08-24   100        1      2
2017-08-23   102        2      2,008600
2017-08-22   101        3      2,004321
2017-08-21   103        4      2,012837
2017-08-18   103        5      2,012837
```

So I tried this for-loop:

```
for column in df:
    tmp_df = df[column]
    tmp_df['RN'] = range(1, len(tmp_df) + 1) # to create a new column with the row number
    tmp_df['LOG'] = np.log(df[column]) # to create a new column with the LOG
```

However this doesn't print the new columns next to col1, but one below the other. The result looks like this:

```
Name: col1, Length: 86, dtype: object
Date
2017-08-24 00:00:00                                                100
2017-08-23 00:00:00                                                102
2017-08-22 00:00:00                                                101
2017-08-21 00:00:00                                                103
2017-08-18 00:00:00                                                103
RN,"range(1, 86)"
LOG,"Date
2017-08-24    2
2017-08-23    2,008600
2017-08-22    2,004321
2017-08-21    2,012837
2017-08-18    2,012837
```

00:00:00 was added to the date in the first part...

I also tried something with assign:

```
tmp_df = tmp_df.assign(LN=np.log(df[column]))
```

But this results in "AttributeError: "'Series' object has no attribute 'assign'""

It'd really be great if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you would like the output to look like? It's not clear to me what the final result should be

Comment: Hi John, I am trying to create a new data form for each column and it should contain the original column c1 - cN and the calculated values next to it, e.g. row number and LOG of c1. I tried to show this in the second code fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is a good idea, but you need to create pandas Series in new columns this way:

```
for column in df:
    df['RN ' + column] = pd.Series(range(1, len(df[column]) + 1))
    df['Log ' + column] = pd.Series(np.log(df[column]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I figured it out. :)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
...
for column in df:
    tmp_res=pd.DataFrame(data=df[column])
    newcol=range(1, len(df) + 1)
    tmp_res=tmp_res.assign(RN=newcol)
    newcol2=np.log(df[column])
    tmp_res=tmp_res.assign(LN=newcol2)
```

This prints all columns next to each other:

```
            col1       RN      LOG
Date                                        
2017-08-24   100        1      2
2017-08-23   102        2      2.008600
2017-08-22   101        3      2.004321
2017-08-21   103        4      2.012837
2017-08-18   103        5      2.012837
```

Now I can go on processing them or put it all in a csv / excel file. 
Thanks for all your suggestions!